# How to plot a large ctree() to avoid overlapping nodes

Tags: r, output, decision-tree

When I plotted the decision tree result from `ctree()` from `party` package, the font was too big and the box was also too big. They are overlapping other nodes.

Is there a way to customize the output from `plot()` so that the box and the font would be smaller ?

Comment: JPC, you better check  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13772715/show-volume-in-each-node-using-ctree-plot-in-r   to show N =

Answer (score 32, accepted):

The short answer seems to be, no, you cannot change the font size, but there are some good other options.

I know of three possible solutions.  First, you can change other parameters in the plot to make it more compact. Second, you can write it to a graphic file and view that file.  Third, you can use an alternative implementation of ctree() in the partykit package, which is a newer package by some of the same authors.

### Default Plot Example

```
library(party)
airq <- subset(airquality, !is.na(Ozone))
airct <- ctree(Ozone ~ ., data = airq, 
               controls = ctree_control(maxsurrogate = 3))
plot(airct)  #default plot, some crowding with N hidden on leafs
```

[image: default plot]

### Simplified plot

```
# simpler version of plot
plot(airct, type="simple",           # no terminal plots
  inner_panel=node_inner(airct,
       abbreviate = TRUE,            # short variable names
       pval = FALSE,                 # no p-values
       id = FALSE),                  # no id of node
  terminal_panel=node_terminal(airct, 
       abbreviate = TRUE,
       digits = 1,                   # few digits on numbers
       fill = c("white"),            # make box white not grey
       id = FALSE)
   )
```

[image]

This is somewhat better and one might be able to improve it further.  To figure out these details, I originally did `class(airct)` which returned "BinaryTree".  Armed with this info, I started reading `?plot.BinaryTree`

### Write to a file

A second simple solution is to write the plot to a file and then view the file. You may need to play with the settings to find the best fit.

```
png("airct.png", res=80, height=800, width=1600) 
   plot(airct) 
dev.off()
```

### Plot with partykit package instead

Finally, you can use a newer and not-yet-finished re-implementation of the party package by some of the same authors.  At this point (Dec 2012), the only function they have re-done is `ctree()`.  This version allows you to change font size.

```
    library(partykit) 
    airct <- ctree(Ozone ~ ., data = airq)
    class(airct)  # different class from before
    # "constparty" "party"  
plot(airct, gp = gpar(fontsize = 6),     # font size changed to 6
  inner_panel=node_inner,
  ip_args=list(
       abbreviate = TRUE, 
       id = FALSE)
  )
```

[image]

Here I have left the leafs in their default setting because I have frankly never figured out how to get it to work the way I want. I suspect this has to do with the fact that the package is incomplete (as of Dec 2012). You can read about the plot method starting with `?plot.party`

Comment: Thank you , Matt . Do you by chance know a way I could show N = , to every circle nodes ? I have been trying to look that up, but couldn't find it. Thanks again

Comment: I don't, I'm afraid.  If you are willing to switch methods you could certainly do it with rpart: `library(partykit);airct= rpart(Ozone ~ ., data = airq);plot(airct);text(test,use.n=T, all=T)`  For any method, you should be able to determine the Ns, it's just that they vary in how flexible the plotting method is.

Answer (score 3):

Another option (that doesn't change what you want but does potentially solve the underlying problem) is to change the size of the figure itself, as I learned in my class for my assignment.

Replace the r in the below:

```
{r}
```

with:

```
{r, fig.width=X, fig.height=Y}
```

where the X and Y need to be replaced by numbers chosen by you depending on what size you think works better.

[This website](https://sebastiansauer.github.io/figure_sizing_knitr/), talks about doing this in more detail and universally throughout the document.