# show volume in each node using ctree , plot in R

Tags: r, model, data-mining

can any one please show me how to add volume in each of the nodes , instead of the final node volume

```
t <- ctree(is_return ~ a + b + c)    
plot(t, type="simple")
```

and my tree would look like

[image]

how can I modified that plot where it would show N= on every circle nodes , not only the black or the final node.

Thanks

Comment: Can you supply   a reproducible example  please? And explain what 's N?

Comment: Oh,N in here is volume , say of the sample, N = 100 , meanings 100 fall into the black square box. but I want to add N in box b and c .. Say if 150 fall into b oval, I want to add N = 150 in there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[image]

The idea is to specify a panel functions for plotting  inner nodes.

I generate some data, and the tree

```
lls <- data.frame(N = gl(3, 50, labels = c("A", "B", "C")), 
                  a = rnorm(150) + rep(c(1, 0,150)),
                  b = runif(150))
pond= sample(1:5,150,replace=TRUE)
tt <- ctree(formula=N~a+b, data=lls,weights = pond)
```

The custom inner plot function. I draw a circle where i write the some of weights.

```
innerWeights <- function(node){
  grid.circle(gp = gpar(fill = "White", col = 1))
  mainlab <- paste( node$psplit$variableName, "\n(n = ")
  mainlab <- paste(mainlab, sum(node$weights),")" , sep = "")
  grid.text(mainlab,gp = gpar(col='red'))
}
```

I plot the tree

```
plot(tt, type='simple', inner_panel = innerWeights)
```

PS: the results depends on a  random generated data, so you will not probably get the same plot.

Comment: @JPC you are welcome. Next time please try to produce a good reproducible example. when I have time I'll do version with ggplot2 inner_function.

Comment: I 'm trying to add back node labels ("A", "B", "C" )  into the inner_panel, but didn't have any success. Could you please show me how to ? Thank you.

Comment: @JPC One hint , put a browser() in the begining of innerWeights , and see your node argument...

Comment: thank you ! I need to send you a thank you card! really ! I am very new to R , but the R community has been great to newbies like me.

Comment: @JPC Welcome to R but I am a newbie too ! Do you use R for work or study?

Comment: for work. I am a sas user, and it was my first programming language. But just started R this 2 weeks ago. and I am going back to school soon..

Answer (score 0):

When exporting the decision tree, change the dimensions of the image. for a decision tree with 200 terminal nodes the width should be about 30.000.